# Can we use a variable for two main.yml which are different foler of same repo

Tags: azure, ansible

In Azure Repos I have two main.yml in different folders . One of main.yml is installing list of packages and another is validating those packages installed or not. Everytime I add a new package to be installed. I need to add the same in another yaml. Is there any way that When I update the package name in one yaml that will be applicable or taken to another yaml aswell.
I cant merge both of them as Am using for different pipelines.

```
#This is one main.yml
- name: install basic packages
  action: >
    {{ ansible_pkg_mgr }} name={{ item }} state=present update_cache=yes
  with_items:
    - vim
    - tmux
    - mosh
#This is another
- name:Check for packages
  shell: rpm vim tmux mosh
  register: packages_status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: *"Can we use a variable for two main.yml which are in different folders of the same repo?"*

A: This can be accomplished by a variable declared on any precedence level. The details depend on what hosts or what groups of hosts will use this variable. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For example, let's take a simple case with one host `test_01` and list of the packages `pkg_list` declared in the `host_vars`.

```sh
shell> cat hosts
test_01
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/test_01 
pkg_list: [vim, tmux, mosh]
```

The playbook below includes two roles to install and validate the packages

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: install
        tasks_from: main.yml
    - include_role:
        name: validate
        tasks_from: main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/install/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: install {{ pkg_list }}
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/validate/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: validate {{ pkg_list }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

PLAY [test_01] ****

TASK [include_role : install] ****
TASK [install : debug] ****
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: install ['vim', 'tmux', 'mosh']

TASK [include_role : validate] ****
TASK [validate : debug] ****
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: validate ['vim', 'tmux', 'mosh']
```

Comment: @VladmirBotka  {{ pkg_list }} is not working under with-items

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways.

The better way.

Use ansible role and put in group_vars

```
roles/
  role_name/
    tasks/
    files/
    vars/
group_vars/
```

source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout

The easy way :

use `include_vars`

```
- name: load vars files
  include_vars:
    dir: path
    file: vars.yml
```

source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html